# Python Beginner hangman trouble

Tags: python

Im new to python and I was wondering if I can get some help. I don't know why my code is not replacing my "_" with the user_answer. Anything helps, thanks.

```
# Hangman Project

import random

choices = ["Up", "The Hulk", "Iron Man", "Spider man", "Batman"]
answer = list(random.choice(choices))

display = []
display.extend(answer)

for x in range(len(answer)):
    display[x] = "_"
print(" ".join(display))

count = len(answer)
guesses = 0


while guesses < len(answer):
    user_guess = input("Enter in a letter: ")
    user_guess = user_guess.lower
    print(guesses)
    guesses += 1
    for x in range(len(answer)):
        if answer[x] == user_guess:
            display[x] = user_guess
            guesses += 1

print(answer)
```

Comment: Isn't this line: `user_guess = user_guess.lower` going to assign a reference to the function lower, instead of calling `user_guess.lower()` and assigning the string result?

Comment: What is your code suppose to do? It looks like the `answer` variable may hold more than "answer". Does your program have one answer or multiple answers?

Answer (score 1):

First things first: I recommend you run your code in [pythontutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import%20random%0A%0Achoices%20%3D%20%5B%22Up%22,%20%22The%20Hulk%22,%20%22Iron%20Man%22,%20%22Spider%20man%22,%20%22Batman%22%5D%0Aanswer%20%3D%20list%28random.choice%28choices%29%29%0A%0Adisplay%20%3D%20%5Bc%20if%20c%20%3D%3D%20%22%20%22%20else%20%22_%22%20for%20c%20in%20answer%5D%0A%0Acount%20%3D%20len%28answer%29%0Aguesses%20%3D%200%0A%0A%0Awhile%20guesses%20%3C%20len%28answer%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20user_guess%20%3D%20input%28%22Enter%20in%20a%20letter%3A%20%22%29%0A%20%20%20%20user_guess%20%3D%20user_guess.lower%0A%20%20%20%20print%28guesses%29%0A%20%20%20%20guesses%20%2B%3D%201%0A%20%20%20%20for%20x%20in%20range%28len%28answer%29%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20answer%5Bx%5D%20%3D%3D%20user_guess%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20display%5Bx%5D%20%3D%20user_guess%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20guesses%20%2B%3D%201%0A%0Aprint%28answer%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false) and see some funny things going on that you've probably not intended. For example: The space in "spider man" is also replaced with an underscore.

Additionally, in the setup I recommend replacing this:

```
display = []
display.extend(answer)

for x in range(len(answer)):
    display[x] = "_"
print(" ".join(display))
```

With this oneliner: `display = [c if c == " " else "_" for c in answer]`. Added benefit is that it keeps a space actually a space.

Finally, you're comparing the guess to the a function because you're missing `()` behind `.lower`. A letter is never equal to the function because you're not invoking it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @tcdejong's answer, when the user has guessed correctly you are adding the correct guess to the `display` list but then not actually displaying it.  You could update this section to:

```
if answer[x].lower() == user_guess.lower():
    display[x] = user_guess
    print(" ".join(display))
    guesses += 1
```